# Using MSTest as site/environment monitoring tool

Tags: monitoring, mstest

We currently use Hp SiteScope for monitoring synthetic transactions across some of our web apps. This works pretty well except for the licensing cost for each synthetic transaction makes it prohibitive to ensure adequate coverage across our applications.

So, an alternative would be to use SiteScope's URL monitoring which can basically call a URL and then provide some basic checks for the certain strings. With that approach, I'd like to create a page that either calls a bunch of pages or try to tap into a MSTest group somehow to run tests.

In the end, I'd like a set of test cases that can be used against multiple environments to be used for production verification, uptime, status, etc.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at System Center Operations Manager 2007?

I'm just getting started, but it appears to do what you are describing in your question.

We are looking to monitoring our data center and the a web application...from the few things I have found on the web it is going to fit our need.

**Update**

I've since moved to Application Insights.  A great overview can be found here, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability/

There are two methods one can use, a simple ping, or record a multi-step synthetic user "experience".  Basically you act as a user, and using IE and a Visual Studio Web Test project you record navigating around your site and upload that file to Azure.

For example, I record logging in, navigating a few pages, and then logging out.  As long as all of those events happen in a timely manner the site is in a good operating state.

If the tests fail, take too long to respond for example, I'll get an email alerting me something isn't exactly right.